# how to store data into new file

Tags: perl

I am processing xml file using XML::simple and how can I store this into new file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
  use strict;
   use Data::Dumper; 
 use XML::Simple;

   my $xml = new XML::Simple;
  my $data = $xml->XMLin("data.xml");
     print Dumper($data);
```

I want to store this data into new file.

Comment: If you're just getting started with XML::Simple, please read [this article](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=218480) which describes common pitfalls.  Having said that, XML::Simple is not the best choice of module for "round-tripping" (reading then writing) XML.

Answer (score 4):

This will overwrite or create the file:

```
open(my $outfile, ">/path/to/some/filename.xml") or die "Could not open file: $!";
print $outfile $xml->XMLOut($data);
close($outfile);
```

Note that `XML::Simple` will likely change the structure of your file so this really only makes sense if you're changing something.

Comment: The `XMLout()` method (note capitalisation) also accepts an `OutputFile` option, so you could simply say: `$xml->XMLout($data, OutputFile => '/path/to/some/filename.xml');`

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply and your using XMLout() function so it cange my data into xml format once again, is there any way to sotre my XMLin data($data)into file or any other modules.